# Ошибка в VsCode

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

Такая проблема. При импортировании проекта в IDE, она крашится. Если что, версия VsCODE на ARM64 (у меня макбук м2, линукс виртуальный). Как решить эту проблему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]